# Zenmap Showing Filtered for iptables REJECT Rule

Tags: vmware, iptables, nmap

I've been recently messing around on my VMWare Ubuntu 15.10, and decided to test out my iptables and see if my Zenmap on my Windows host machine would recognize the ports being blocked. 
However, when I apply this rule (while logged in as root) to block all incoming HTTP traffic:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT
```

and hit scan on a regular scan, Zenmap will show the port as filtered, not closed. I'm trying to get the specific port to be closed and shown on the "Not shown: ### closed ports", but I've researched trying to close a specific port and all I've been getting is DROP or REJECT.

I'm currently using Nmap 7.12 on my Windows 10 host machine and Ubuntu 15.10 on my virtual machine with a NAT connection. My friend tested his rule on his Fedora 23, which stated:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT
```

and upon a rescan, the port showed that it was closed. I tried the same exact command in Ubuntu, and I still got that the port was filtered. Would there be a command for a specific port for Ubuntu?